Issues with System Update Manager
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, the System Update Manager is not functioning correctly. It either hangs or fails to check for updates. The Update Manager hangs or shows an error message when trying to check for updates.
So far I have tried to manually update via terminal.
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt upgrade

Hence, what could be causing the System Update Manager to malfunction after the upgrade? Thank you.

The commands in order that you should be running in terminal to do an update are. sudo apt update and on a separate line after sudo apt upgrade This is not what you show in the question as what you have tried.

There might be a problem with the package installation or configuration process on your system. Sometimes broken packages can prevent the Update Manager from working correctly. Run the following commands to fix any broken packages:
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install

